# Change keyboard layout xmir

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet

I am a happy owner of the M10 tablet. Only when using the legacy x11 apps my keyboard layout does not follow the system settings. From what i understand these run in a container, so is there any way to change the keyboad layout in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue with my M10 tablet. I will post an update if I find a solution

little update:there is already a bug filed on launchpad
https://bugs.launchpad.net/libertine/+bug/1566487

hope this can help

Comment: I saw that bug report before. I switched to the rc-proposed images and reciveived the patch today.